# Many-stepped procedure with several possibilities for errors- call each step separately from outer class, or have one method?

Tags: java, error-handling

Newbie here.. I'm wondering about what is best practice in the following case:

I use the MVC-pattern. My Controller-class needs to call the Model-class to perform a procedure. This procedure has 4 steps. In the 3 first steps, if something goes wrong, the Model will produce a list of Strings, that the Controller must ensure is displayed to the user, in addition to an error message. In the last step, the Model will produce a Map, that again the Controller must ensure is showed to the user. In the last step, a Timeout could also occur..

What is the best way to handle this?

I have made two rough drafts of suggestions below.

Alternative 1:

```
public class Model{


    public List<String> step1(){
        // return empty list if ok, fill list otherwise
    }

    public List<String> step2(){    // return empty list if ok, fill list otherwise}

    public Map<String, String> step3(){     // return empty list if ok, fill list otherwise}
}


public class Controller{

    Model myMOdel; 

    public void doProcedure(){

        List<String> list = myModel.step1();
        if(list.size() != 0){
            String errormessage = "Step 1 error message"
            // make sure View display list and errormessage
            return;
        }


        list = myModel.step2();
        if(list.size() != 0){
            String errormessage = "Step 2 error message"
            // make sure View display list and errormessage
            return;
        }

        Map<String, String> map = myModel.step3();
        if(map.size()!=0){
            String errormessage = "Step 3 error message"
            // make sure View display map and errormessage
            return;
        }

        // make View display "procedure ok" message to user
}
```

What I don't like about this is that it opens up for the possibility for the Controller to forget to do a step, or do the steps in the wrong order.

Alternative 2:

```
public class Model {

    final static int STEP1_ERROR;
    final static int STEP2_ERROR;
    final static int STEP3_ERROR;

    private void  step1() throws ModelException{
        List<String> list;
        if(somethingwentwrong){
            throw new ModelException(STEP1_ERROR, "errormessage for step1", list)
        }
    }

    private void step2() throws ModelException {.
            List<String> list;
        if(somethingwentwrong){
            throw new ModelException(STEP2_ERROR, "errormessage for step2", list)
        }
    }

    private void step3() throws ModelException{.
        Map<String, string> map;
        if(somethingwentwrong){
            throw new ModelException(STEP3_ERROR, "errormessage for step3", map)
        }
    }

    public void procedure() throws ModelException{
        step1();
        step2();
        step3();    
    }   
}


public class Controller{

    Model myModel;

    try{
        model.procedure();
    }
    catch(ModelException e){
        switch(e.getErrorNum){
            case // handle error type 1
            case // handle error type 2 etc
        }
    }

}


public class ModelException extends Exception{

    List<String> list;
    Map<String, String> map;
    int errorNum;

    public ModelException(int errorNum, String message,  List<String>){
        ....
    }

    public ModelException(int errorNum, String message,  Map<String><String>){
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd alternative is definitely better. But you can even improve it by replacing the errorNum field by a proper **hierarchy of exceptions** (because each exception type should describe a particular condition in the execution):

```
public class ModelException extends Exception{}

public class Step1ModelException extends ModelException{
    public Step1ModelException(List<String> details) {...}
    public List<String> getDetail(){...}
}

public class Step2ModelException extends ModelException{
    public Step2ModelException(List<String> details) {...}
    public List<String> getDetail(){...}
}

public class Step3ModelException extends ModelException{
    public Step3ModelException(Map<String,String> details) {...}
    public Map<String,String> getDetail(){...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I liked the 2 best as well. I hadn't considered that I could make subclasses like this. Will try :)